# Denseness of functions in a subspace of $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K:=\{f\in C^1[0,1]| f(0)=f(1)=0\}$. I want to show that the functions of the form $x(1-x)f(x)$ with $f\in C^1[0,1]$ are dense is $K$ using the $C^1[0,1]$ norm. I am not sure even if this is true. I want to use this to show that the polynomials of the form $x(1-x)p(x)$ ($p(x)$ is a polynomial) are dense in $K$.

So basically I have to show that for every $g\in K$ and for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $f\in C^1[0,1]$ such that $\|g-x(1-x)f(x)\|_{C^1[0,1]}<\epsilon$. 
I know that polynomials are dense in $C^1[0,1]$ and I was hoping to use that for $x(1-x)$ part but since $f$ is multiplied by it I have no idea how I can use triangle inequality to break the norm.

Comment: Note that for a polynomial $q$ it holds $q(x)=x(1-x)p(x)$ iff $q(0)=q(1)=0$.

Comment: If $p_n$ converges to $f$, then $p_n(0)$ and $p_n(1)$ converge to $0$. Thus, $q_n(x)=p_n(x)−(p_n(1)−p_n(0))x+p_n(0)$ converges to $f$ and satisfies $q_n(0)=q_n(1)=0$.

Comment: @ Chris Apostol, Thanks! totally got your point. I can use it to prove what I am originally after, without bothering with what I asked. It would be nice though to see if the above proposition is right or wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose a polynomial $\gamma$ such that
$|f'(x) - \gamma(x)| < {1 \over 2} \epsilon$ for all $x$.

Let $d = \int_0^1 \gamma(x)dx$ and note that
$\int_0^1 (f'(t)-\gamma(t))dt = -\int_0^1 \gamma(t)dt = -d$ and
so $|d| < {1 \over 2} \epsilon$.

Let $\tilde{\gamma}(x) = \gamma(x) -d $ and note that
$|f'(x) - \tilde{\gamma}(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ and
$\int_0^1 \tilde{\gamma}(t) dt = 0$.

Define $p(x) = \int_0^x \tilde{\gamma}(t)dt$, note that $p$ is
a polynomial, $p(0) = p(1) = 0$ and 
$|f(x)-p(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$.

Since $p(0)=p(1)$ we can write $p(x) = x(1-x) q(x)$ for some
polynomial $q$.

Hence polynomials of the form $x \mapsto x(1-x) q(x)$ are
$C^1[0,1]$ dense in $K$.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess there is a problem here. Based on the given proof for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a polynomial $p$ such that $\|f-p\|_{C^1[0,1]}<\epsilon$. This means that $p$ converges to 0 at 0 and 1 but dose not necessarily mean that p(0)=p(1)=0 exactly. I think we have to add what @Chris Apostol  pointed out in the comments and reconstruct another polynomial $q$ that converges to $p$ and is exactly 0 at the endpoints and then argue that it can be written as $x(1-x)l(x)$.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying. The polynomial $p$ above satisfies $p(0)=p(1) = 0$.  That is the whole point of the above argument. There is no convergence issue here. The above result shows that the polynomials in $K$ are $C^1[0,1]$ dense in $K$.

Comment: Ya, thanks I got it. I kinda mixed it up with the solution I was working on. Yours is obviously better.